# Laravel Eloquent relation depending on type of item

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have model `Product`, it has 2 types: `Lamps` and `Bulbs`. A lamp have set of attributes that differs from a bulb, so I have 2 another models `Lamp` and `Bulb` which represent set of attributes. What type of relation from Product to attribute model should I implement in this situation?

I've been trying one-to-one relation, but in my situation this second "one" differs from product's type.

I've been thinking of **EAV** pattern, but I don't want tons of joins in my architecture right now because I don't need more than these two types of item.

What would you suggest?

**UPD1:** here are the tables (simplified):

```
mysql> show columns from products;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name        | varchar(127) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| price       | double       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| old_price   | double       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| category_id | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show columns from lamps;
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| product_id | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| width      | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| height     | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| length     | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| weight     | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show columns from bulbs;
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| product_id | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| voltage    | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| power      | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| base       | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| type       | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**UPD2:** I understand that I can use two foreign keys in products table and set up only one of them for each record, but is there some more elegant scheme for this situation?

Comment: What's your table set up for this?

Comment: Ross, see update.